# Change <input> value to an icon on resize

Tags: jquery, html, input, resize

I've done a bit of searching on Google but it seems that most people try to do this with buttons, not inputs, which seem to me like different stories.

When users resize my webpage to a width less than 640px, I want to change the value attribute of an input element to an icon of a magnifying glass represented in DOM like this:

```
<i class="fa fa-search"></i>
```

How do I do this? So far, here is my code:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    ($(document).width() < 640) ? $("input[id='searchsubmit']").attr("value", "+") : $("input[id='searchsubmit']").attr("value", "Search");
});
```

Replacing the "+" with the above icon element prints the entire element markup itself. Thanks so much!

Comment: since you're using jquery, I believe you can just use $("selector").val()

Comment: Right, but changing the value to <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
will make the input field literally display "<i class="fa fa-search"></i>"

Comment: You can't put HTML in an input. It renders as HTML as you can see. You'd need to replace the input.

Answer (score 1):

Going on a couple assumptions here. You're using Font Awesome (thus the `fa fa-search`), and you're attempting to insert that glyph as a value into an `<input type="submit" value="[glyph here]">` when the window is resized below 640px. But the browser is inserting the raw html rather than interpreting it as the glyph.

Perhaps a better solution would be to have two submit buttons, and show/hide the correct one based on screen width. Something like the following html:

```
<input type="submit" value="Search" id="searchsubmit">
<i class="fa fa-search" style="display:none;" id="searchsubmit2"></i>
```

And then some jquery:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    if ($(document).width() < 640) {
        $('#searchsubmit').hide();
        $('#searchsubmit2').show();
    }
    else {
        $('#searchsubmit').show();
        $('#searchsubmit2').hide();
    }
});

// a little css for the glyph
$('#searchsubmit2').css('cursor','pointer');

//submit the form when the glyph is clicked
$(document).on('click', '#searchsubmit2', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#id-of-form-to-submit').submit();
});

// trigger window resize event on page load so correct submit is displayed
$(window).trigger('resize');
```